# Python Using RandInt to Generate 3-Digit Pattern: Syntax Error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm reading a beginners text on Python Programming. And I'm getting a syntax error that, seemingly, is a typo in the text. The code is:

```py
class LaserWeaponArmory(Scene):

    def enter(self):
        print(dedent("""
            You do a dive roll into the Weapon Armory, crouch and scan
            the room for more GOthon that might be hiding. It's dead
            quiet, too quiet.  You stand up and run to the far side of
            the room and find the neutron bomb in its container.
            There's a keypad lock on the box and you need the code to
            get the bomb out. If you get the code wrong 10 times then
            the lock closes forever and you can't get the bomb.  The
            code is 3 digits.
            """))

        code = f"{randint(1,9)}{randint(1,9)}{randint(1,9)}"
        guess = input("[keypad]> ")
        guesses = 0

        while guess != code and guesses <10:
            print("BZZZZEDDD!")
            guesses += 1
            guess = input("[keypad]> ")

        if guess == code:
            print(dedent("""
                The container clicks open and the seal breaks, letting
                gas out.  You grab the neutron bomb and run as fast as
                you can to the bridge where you must place it in the
                right spot.
                """))
            return 'the_bridge'
        else:
            print(dedent("""
                The lock buzzes one last time and then you hear a
                sickening melting sound as the mechanism is fused
                together.  You decide to sit there, and finally the
                Gothons blow up the ship from their ship and you die.
                """))
            return 'death'
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
File "ex43.py", line 121
    code = f"{randint(1,9)}{randint(1,9)}{randint(1,9)}"
                                                       ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

So it seems to be trying to create a 3 digit pattern of random numbers?

Comment: What python version do you use ? Because this is good, but f-string are new from ptthon 3.6

Comment: Is this the full code? Where is the line 121?

Comment: Ahhh. This was it. I'm on a new computer with a fresh install of Anaconda. But my path wasn't set up correctly.

Answer (score 1):

f strings are supported from python 3.6+

try:

```
code = "".join([str(randint(1,9)) for _ in range(3)])
```

And you might want to use `randint(0,9)` to get also zeros

Comment: It never ceases to amaze me, who would downvote a correct answer and not leave a comment explaining  why ?

Comment: @UriGoren Yeah, that sucks. +1. Also, you can drop the `[`brackets`]` to make it a generator expression since it's the only argument to `join(...)`. So `"".join(str(randint(1,9)) for _ in range(3))`

Answer (score 0):

"randint" module is not imported. Add the following statement

```
from random import randint
```